# how to select random user

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

[image]

i have the following table with its fields, this table has more than 30K user's,

EACH USE'r has more than 1000 records,

userid is named as ANONID , i want to select randomly 100 user with all their records,using MYSQL

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a table of 30,000 and a single sample, you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
order by rand()
limit 100;
```

This does exactly what you want.  It will take a few seconds to return.

If performance is an issue, there are other more complicated methods for sampling the data.  A simple method reduces the number of rows before the `order by`.  So a 5% sample will speed the query and here is one method for doing that:

```
select t.*
from t
where rand() < 0.05
order by rand()
limit 100;
```

EDIT:

You want what is called a *clustered* sample or hierarchical sample.  Use a subquery:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select userid
      from (select distinct userid from t) t
      order by rand()
      limit 100
     ) tt
     on t.userid = tt.userid;
```

Comment: actually i tried this . but it give's me only 100 user's with their 100 record. in my table a single user has more than 1000 records .

Comment: it worked . i appreciate you'r work bundle of thanks . it is really helpful, (y)

Answer (score 4):

"rand()" function as mentioned in earlier answers do not work in SQL 2k12 . for SQL use following query to get random 100 rows using "newid()" function 
("newid()" is built in function for SQL)

```
select * from table
order by newid()
offset 0 rows
fetch  next 100 rows only
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 100
```

It is slow, but it works.

Comment: actually i tried this . but it give's me only 100 users with a single record. in my table a single user has more than 1000 records